# Is it possible to open a 3rd party script to open a report in a new tab/window?

Tags: javascript, html

Good evening,

I am having an issue with a script that I have and would like to know if anyone can help.

I have a script which outputs a form on my webpage, and once the form is completed, it generates a report but it sends users away from my page by opening in the same tab.

I was wondering if it's possible to modify the code they gave me to make it open in a new tab - to stop users being directed away from my site.

The code is below:

```html
<div class="reviewmgr-lookup" data-url="https://reviewmgr.com/localfocusdigitalcom"></div>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.reviewmgr.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, "script", "reviewmgr-wjs");</script>
```

Comment: Not from the code they gave you; you'll need to contact them directly and ask if they can provide such functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Would I not be able to make use of the reviewmgr-lookup div and add some kind of attribute? That is outside of the iframe which the JS generates.

Comment: The form is inside an iframe showing a page from a different domain. For security reasons it's impossible to change the document displayed in the iframe.

Comment: Why not have a page having a button like "Get a report", which opens your page in a new tab; after submission user has your site, and the report in two different tabs.